# Set same margins to footer as for body

Tags: html, css

I've a footer that is divided in 2 columns,  1 to the left and 1 to the right.

[image]

But I'd like to set the margins so the content of the footer is align with the body (with the images you see there).

```
I've used Bootstrap4 tags (container) for the body but it is not working for the footer.
```

**I'm expecting to replicate this:**

[image]

**Codepen**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vwMowX

**footer:**

```
<!-- /* NEW FOOTER */ -->

{% load staticfiles %}

<style>
    ul > li {
        display: inline-block;
        /* You can also add some margins here to make it look prettier */
        zoom:1;
        *display:inline;
        /* this fix is needed for IE7- */
    }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="footer-navbar" class="row footer navbar-fixed-bottom padding-top2 padding-bottom2">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="">

                <nav class="">
                    <div class="mx-auto d-sm-flex d-block flex-sm-nowrap">

                            <ul class="">
                                <li class="">
                                    <a class="" href="{% url 'shop:quienes_somos' %}">¿Quiénes somos?</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a class="" href="{% url 'shop:como_comprar' %}">¿Cómo comprar?</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                    <a class="" href="{% url 'shop:contactanos' %}">Contáctanos</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                    </div>
                </nav>

                <ul class="left footer-links footer-interact hidden-md-down">
                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/stickersgallito" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" title="Twitter"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/stickersgallito" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" title="Instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://facebook.com/stickersgallito" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" title="Facebook"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/stickersgallito" rel="nofollow noopener" target="_blank" title="YouTube"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">

            <div class="">
                <p><img src="{% static 'img/home/peru-flag.png' %}"
                    width="40px" height="40px">Perú</p>
            </div>

                <div class="right footer-legal">
                        <span>&copy; 2019 StickersGallito</span>
                <a href="/legal/privacy">Privacy</a> &amp; <a href="/legal/terms">Terms</a>

                    </div>

        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE 1**

adding the container-fluid div and container div don't allow the background to go full width.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to apply the same amount of padding / margin that you've applied in the **body** to the **footer**

Comment: @Manu I've used based bootstrap container tag, Don't know why I cannot do the same to the footer.

Comment: Apply the ```container``` class in your **inner div** which has ```id="footer-navbar"```

Comment: @Manu that does not work, you may try it on the codepen provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jooNYJ#anon-login

All changes I've done are in the first 2 `divs`

They should look like:

```
<div id="footer-navbar">
  <div class="container row footer navbar-fixed-bottom padding-top2 my-0 mx-auto padding-bottom2">
    ***content***
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that works but the right part is a little bit offset, related to the squared images.

Comment: To be fair, there's a lot that can be improved when it comes to HTML semantics. The structure it's a bit of a mess which makes things much more difficult to display on the page e.g. you should not be using ```<br>``` but instead separate elements with ```margin```/```padding```; images should be wrapped into an unordered list ```ul``` with ```li``` rather than ```div``` and more. Ideally you want to use **flexbox** classes to arrange elements on the page. It will bring a huge improvement to the layout.

Comment: You've some example I can look on?

Answer (score 1):

The class `container-fluid` sets `width` to `100%`, `container` doesn't. You need to have an inner wrapping div with the `container` class.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        *** Put your footer in here ***
    </div>
</div>
```

The inner div will be centered.

Comment: normally you use 1 container or the other, not both

Comment: @zgood This is a fairly common approach if you want the outer div to stretch the entire screen but not the inner div. For example if you want a background color to stretch to full width, but not all the content in the div.

Comment: @Azer see the update 1, any new structure of the html is accepted.

Comment: @Azer sure that makes sense, but it still doesn't need to be a container... a `<div class="bg-primary">` would make more sense to me - don't need the extra padding containers add. but ya it really doesn't matter too much I agree